# How to cache layout content in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, caching, optimization, layout, page-caching

How would you implement caching of the layout content in Zend Framework?

In the `layout.phtml` I do: `$this->layout->content` and I want the content of this variable to be cached. The other widgets from the layout are real time (or cached other way).

The best bets are:

- static cache (the fastest)
- page cache

My pages already have unique page id (`canonical`), so it could be used as page cache tag.

Potentially looks like I have to overload `__get` property of the layout.

I'm trying to do something like the layout of SO (user panel at the top, rest cached for all).
I assume, site should work without JavaScript.

Comment: I guess $this->layout->content contains the view content of the controller? So you want to cache the result of an action?

Comment: @Fge Results of all of the actions (or almost all, some excluded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Front Controller Cache plugin](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372) weierophinney describes. The problem probably is that you don't want the script to stop on cache hit. So you don't `exit;` the the script, you could work with `$request->setDispatched(true)` within the plugin. (You'd need a new request-object for every different cacheable).
Another approach could be that you don't use the `dispatchLoopStartup` but the `preDispatch` in your plugin and reset the dispatching there.
They way to go actually depends on how you load all the other stuff (be it cached or not). (E.g. the ActionStack pushes a new request to the dispatcher).